# How to disable a Mobile Redirect?

Tags: php, redirect, mobile, wordpress

I'm having an issue with a mobile redirect in a website.

The website: [ShawEsquire.com](http://shawesquire.com) when accessed from a mobile is redirected to [Mobile.ShawEsquire.mobi](http://mobile.shawesquire.mobi)

The website is in WordPress and I installed a Splash page but I'm not able to see it because of this redirect.

I checked the header to see if there's anything for redirecting to the mobile domain but it seems clear.

Can you point me out to the right direction to where I should be looking please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by going to the host and deactivating the mobile option, the host is GoDaddy. Hope this helps someone is your having the same issue.